# How to view data from database in a new page after successfully logged in

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to figure out how to automatically display user data from database in a new page after they're successfully logged in using VB.

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient

Public Class guardianlogin
Dim MySqlConn As New MySqlConnection
Dim reader As MySqlDataReader
Dim command As MySqlCommand

Private Sub ManageCustomer_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    MySqlConn.ConnectionString = "server=localhost ; user id=root ; password = '1234' ; database = 'bengkel1_farah' "

End Sub

Private Sub Label1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Label1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Try
        MySqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from guardian where g_ID ='" & TextBox1.Text & "' and password ='" & TextBox2.Text & "'"
        command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MySqlConn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0
        While reader.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While

        If count = 1 Then
            guardianview.Show()
            Me.Hide()

            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()

        Else
            MessageBox.Show("YOUR USERNAME OR PASSWORD ARE INCORRECT. PLEASE TRY AGAIN")
            TextBox1.Clear()
            TextBox2.Clear()

        End If
        MySqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MySqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

what should I add or remove to my coding?

Comment: Maybe better suited would be http://codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: there are too many codes you can change: e.g. remove label1_click.  if you are sure no 2 record with same id, just replace while reader.read by if reader.read because count is impossible to be greater then 1

Comment: me.hide?  why?  what is guardianview.show?  if you want to display data, create some more labels and replace those label.text with values from sql

Comment: you can store TextBox1.Text to a public variable then query it for display in the next form.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that your guardianlogin class is used to simply validate the user login and your guardianview is used to display the data from the database?

If that is right them you need to put your labels on your guardianview form and update the labels before showing the form.

```
guardianview.Load()
guardianview.lblUsername.text = USERNAME_DATA_FROM_DATABASE_HERE
guardianview.lblPassword.text = PWD_DATA_FROM_DATABASE_HERE
guardianview.lblAdminMsg.text = MESSAGE_DATA_FROM_DATABASE_HERE
guardianview.Show()
Me.Hide()
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming **guardianview.Show()** is the page you are trying to show your user's data. So basically you just create some **labels** and retrieve some strings/integers from your [MySql](https://www.mysql.com/) database. Here's some codes, that may give you a better understanding.

```
Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from bengkel1_farah.guardian where g_ID='" & Form1.TextBox1.Text & "'"
        command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
        reader = command.ExecuteReader
        While READER.Read
            Label15.Text = READER.GetInt32("ID") 'You use GetInt32 to get integers
            Label31.Text = READER.GetString("Name") 'You use GetString to get strings
            Label23.Text = READER.GetString("Email")
        End While
        MysqlConn.Close()

Catch ex As MySqlException
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
End Try
```

I tried to be clear enough, anyway if you still face troubles, I will try to explain more.